# how to add datagridview column1 and column2 into column3 in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, addition

I am trying to add column1 value to column2 and have to insert into column2

my code is

Event is **CellLeave**

```
if (dgrVwEmp.Columns[dgrVwEmp.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Name == "ol")
 {
    int ol;
    int.TryParse(dgrVwEmp.Rows[dgrVwEmp.CurrentCell.RowIndex]
                         .Cells["ol"].EditedFormattedValue.ToString(), out  ol);

    int leavs;
    int.TryParse(dgrVwEmp.Rows[dgrVwEmp.CurrentCell.RowIndex]
                         .Cells["ttlLeaves"].Value.ToString(), out leavs);

    int dys;
    int.TryParse(dgrVwEmp.Rows[dgrVwEmp.CurrentCell.RowIndex]
                         .Cells["ttlWrkng"].Value.ToString(), out dys);

    dgrVwEmp.Rows[dgrVwEmp.CurrentCell.RowIndex]
                         .Cells["ttlLeaves"].Value = (ol + leavs).ToString();
    dgrVwEmp.Rows[dgrVwEmp.CurrentCell.RowIndex]
                         .Cells["ttlWrkng"].Value = (dys - ol).ToString();

 }
```

when I am trying to add like this 1st time is the values are adding and inserting to 3rd field, if I came back to the same cell it is adding again to already added field. How can I add it properly. This is becose I am using Cell leave even. Is there any other way or other event to do this properly

Comment: Not sure the problem is clear.  Do you need a flag that says don't calculate again or something like that?

Comment: yaahh.. thats bettre Idea. but how can I find that the value is changed to calculate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could introduce a variable that holds the old value and when the event is fired, the old value is subtracted from `ttleaves` cell at the same time the new value is added. The opposite should happen with the `ttlWrkng` cell:

```
private int oldValue = 0;

private void dgrVwEmp_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   if (dgrVwEmp.Columns[dgrVwEmp.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Name == "ol")
   {
      int ol;
      int.TryParse(dgrVwEmp.Rows[dgrVwEmp.CurrentCell.RowIndex]
                     .Cells["ol"].EditedFormattedValue.ToString(), out  ol);

      int leavs;
      int.TryParse(dgrVwEmp.Rows[dgrVwEmp.CurrentCell.RowIndex]
                     .Cells["ttlLeaves"].Value.ToString(), out leavs);

      int dys;
      int.TryParse(dgrVwEmp.Rows[dgrVwEmp.CurrentCell.RowIndex]
                     .Cells["ttlWrkng"].Value.ToString(), out dys);

      dgrVwEmp.Rows[dgrVwEmp.CurrentCell.RowIndex]
                     .Cells["ttlLeaves"].Value = (ol + leavs - oldValue).ToString();
      dgrVwEmp.Rows[dgrVwEmp.CurrentCell.RowIndex]
                     .Cells["ttlWrkng"].Value = (dys - ol + oldValue).ToString();

      oldValue = ol;
   }

}
```